# Different error responses when using the JIRA REST API in two instances

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

We have two jira installations at our company. One that we use for our projects and a second one for testing purposes.

I'm working in a project that needs to use the JIRA REST API. For this purpose I'm connecting to our testing instance.

The problem is that while trying out the REST API, I keep getting 400 errors without a single explanation of what went wrong. I just get an HTML with

> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

I was a bit desperate and decided to try it into our real JIRA. To my surpirse the same request gave me a different response:

```
{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"project":"project is required"}}
```

In this case, I do get a meaningful error!
I replicated this easily. I would never get a meaningful error from the test instance, but the real one will always give me one.

I cannot keep trying out stuff in our productive JIRA, but I cannot easily continue working without getting meaningful errors. So, what could be wrong in the testing instance? I could not find any configuration about the 'verbosity' of the API responses.

Comment: what call/request you are sending ? Could you proved request and the data you're sending ?

Comment: @ThePavolC yes, I can, but I doubt that helps. as I said the exactly same request (using curl, I just change the host), returns me different response

Comment: Well, I think both messages are giving you same information. That the data you're sending are not correct. Second message gives you little bit of a hint that you are missing project in your data.

Comment: yes, the problem is that I have a lot of testing to do and I cannot use a production JIRA for this. I need to get the meaningful message from the testing jira!

Comment: I am not asking for help to get the jira request right, but to get the proper message when I dont

Comment: `{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"project":"project is required"}}` well then you need to specify project with your request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73942/discussion-between-thepavolc-and-santiagozky).

Comment: Is the "Accept remote API calls" turned on? (Administration >> System >> General Settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this error is returned not by JIRA but rather by proxy web server that is part of you production configuration.

I suggest you to compare HTTP headers that are sent with working requests from your browser with headers you pass via curl. Googling for the "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand" helps too

Comment: yes, this is actually the problem! the error page is generated by apache not jira. Apache needs to be configured to serve the original error page